# Struts2 disable validation

Tags: struts2

I'm  trying to disable the validation of a method of one class.

I've seen the annotation `@SkipValidation` but it doesn't work.  I tried to put the following interceptor-ref to my action but it doesn't work either.

```xml
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="excludeMethods">ricerca,execute</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

I need to remove the validation of a `Date` field of this class.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Also, if you specify an interceptor configuration in an action's configuration you must specify *all* interceptors. You could just refer to whatever stack you're using and for the param name use `validation.excludeMethods` as well, IIRC.

Comment: with doesn't works i mean it doesn't behaves as i want. Why isn't the validation skipped on the method i annotated  with `@SkipValidation`?

Comment: It should passes through the following interceptor http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/validation/AnnotationValidationInterceptor.html.

Comment: Well, i know "It should", but it doesn't skip it.

Answer (score 0):

What @MohanaRaoSV said is probably the solution:

1. [**`AnnotationValidationInterceptor`**](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/validation/AnnotationValidationInterceptor.html) is the Interceptor that reads the `@SkipValidation` Annotation.
2. <strike>It is NOT part of the DefaultStack, so you have to include it manually;</strike>
3. From your code, it seems you are working with the **`ValidationInterceptor`**, that knows nothing about those annotations.

Be sure to include it in your stack.

**EDIT**: Looking in `struts-default.xml` inside Struts2-core-2.3.15.x.jar, "`validation`" is now mapped to `AnnotationValidationInterceptor`, instead of the old `ValidationInterceptor`; check in your `struts-default.xml`, if you are running an older version of Struts2;